# mysql order by into two different parts

Tags: mysql, sorting, sql-order-by, grouping

I've a situation where i need a double order by. 
Let me try to explain it (for simplicity i've removed unnecessary columns).

**(currentDate = 2017-07-31)**

I've a table called **user** like so

```
 user_id | username | user_changed
 ---------------------------------
 1       | John Doe | 2017-07-31 12:22:58 (less then 48 hours)
 2       | Test name| 2017-07-30 09:17:18 (less the 48 hours)
 4       | itRocks2 | 2017-07-28 07:45:52 (greater then 48 hours)
 3       | itRocks  | 2017-07-29 07:45:52 (greater then 48 hours)
```

Now comes the tricky part. I need to order into two different parts

**Part one:**
 The first part needs to be a random order by user_changed where 
 user_changed is 48 
 hours ago or less.

**Part two:**
Needs to order the remaining users where the user_changed is greater then 48 hours with order by user_changed ASC

So with the example data from our database this should be the result

1       | John Doe | 2017-07-31 12:22:58

2       | Test name| 2017-07-30 09:17:18

These two needs a random order because they are less then 48 hours
All the other users (greater the 48 hours) needs an order by user_changed ASC, like so

3       | itRocks  | 2017-07-29 07:45:52 (example 52 hours)

4       | itRocks2 | 2017-07-28 07:45:52 (example 60 hours)

Also i need a default order by user_id for grouping the users later on in my view. So some queries i've tried:

**query 1**

```
SELECT      *, if(user_changed >= SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 48 HOUR), RAND(), 0) AS rndOrder
FROM        users 
ORDER BY    user_id, rndOrder ASC
```

**query 2**

```
SELECT      *, if(user_changed >= SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 48 HOUR), "true", "false") AS rndOrder
FROM        users 
ORDER BY    user_id ASC,    
            CASE 
                WHEN rndOrder = 1 THEN user_changed RAND()
                WHEN frndOrder = 0 THEN user_changed ASC
            END;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this:

```
SELECT      *
FROM        users 
ORDER BY    user_id ASC,    
        CASE 
            WHEN user_changed <= SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 48 HOUR) THEN
                 ADDDATE( CURDATE(), 1 + (FLOOR( 1 + RAND( ) * 10000 )))
            ELSE user_changed
        END ASC;
```

Basically, keep the order consistent, but set the things from the last 48 hours to be some value in the future with a random date added.

Comment: I've tried your query @Cwallenpoole but it doesn't show like i describe above. First the les then 48 ours. Then all the remaining thus 48 hours and greater sorted by asc

Comment: @Bham I switched a `<` and a `>`.